# How to update a row_num and column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL and I have took over a in-house developed SQL database from another person who had left. Now I am facing issue trying to update via the row_number and column.

The details of the SQL files are as follows and I will like to be able to update via row_number and a particular column (e.g postal code). But I have no idea on how to proceed.

E.g I have a row number 518 whereby the address field and postal code which are filled with wrong information. But I am not able to edit it. It looks like I have to write SQL code to be able to amend this, but I have no prior knowledge of SQL statement.

```
*SELECT TOP 1000 [SalesGroupNo]
      ,[CustomerName]
      ,[Address]
      ,[PostalCode]
      ,[ContractType]
      ,[Segmentation]
      ,[Channel]
      ,[SalesPerson]
      ,[Supervisor]
      ,[Source]
      ,[createDate]
      ,[modifiedDate]
      ,[contactno]
      ,[noofvisit]
      ,[BillingName]
      ,[BillingAddress]
      ,[ContactPerson]
      ,[PaymentTerm]
      ,[Status]
      ,[LastUpdatedBy]
      ,[OutletPostalCode]
      ,[CSPLID]
      ,[StatusDate]
      ,[Group]
      ,[Postal]
      ,[isGroup]
      ,[Remarks]
      ,[BA]
      ,[DateFrom]
      ,[DateTo]
  FROM [OMS].[dbo].[Outlets]*
```

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag, based on `[..]` "quoting" style.

Comment: Does this table have a primary key? You can recognise it as one or more golden key symbols against columns. Without an ORDER BY, the row number is not a reliable field to use to update.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this:

```
UPDATE table SET column1 = expression1, column2 = expression2 WHERE conditions;
```

Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

In various DB systems, the *row number* function returns the sequential number of a row within a result set; in your scenario it may be useful if you have to udpate a particular row given its position in a result set.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms186734(v=sql.105).aspx

As a guideline it's better, if possible, to update via the key of the table instead of the position in a row set.

An update query in T-SQL to update the 518th row of the result set without knowing the value of its primary key, should be:

```
update [OMS].[dbo].[Outlets]
set PostalCode = 'newvalue'
where PK_COLUMN = (
    select PK_COLUMN
    from [OMS].[dbo].[Outlets]
    where ROW_NUMBER = 518)
```

But you have to substitute the `PK_COLUMN` with the name of the column (or columns) of the primary key of you `Outlets` table.

Comment: Hi Andrea, meaning the column should be "postalcode"? Pardon me as I have zero knowledge of SQL. 

As for the 'newvalue', I can key in the alphanumeric?

Comment: The text 'PK_COLUMN' should be replaced with the name of the column (field) that contains unique values for every row (a key filed). The text 'newvalue' should be replaced with the new value of the postal code that you want to update for that particular row.

Comment: In the absence or unique order by that is nondeterministic.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use rom_num function for this.

```
update table
set PostelCode=your_value
from 
 (
    Select row_number() over (partition by table_column order by table_column ) 
     AS SrNo,* from     
    tableName
  )table
  where table.SrNo=your_rowNum
```

Answer (score 0):

Row number is not a unique identifier to identify a particular row in a table. In order to perform an update on a particular row, you have to use an unique identifier. For that you can use a primary key or the row id(not the row number). 
In a sorted result, row number might be seems like a good option, but it isn't.
Ex:

Consider a Table like this,

```
RowID      RowNumber  Name    Salary
239482989     1       john    10000
787934576     2       paul    20000
989984334     3       john    40000
```

Below table represents a sorted version of above using the 'Name' column

```
RowID      RowNumber  Name    Salary
239482989     1       john    10000
989984334     2       john    40000
787934576     3       paul    20000
```

But the above result can be vary the each time you want to sort it. Because it has the same value as 'john' in sorting column of two different rows. So there is no particular method to choose what row should come at first. It works randomly. So when you are updating the table you cannot use the row number, because it will give wrong output sometimes.

I recommend you to use a primary key or row id in updating your table rows.

Answer (score 0):

The table has no row_number column. 
That query has no order by. 
There is no order to those rows. 
The function row_number is nondeterministic in that example. 
Now rows will typically be returned by PK if one exists or the order the rows were entered - but that is not guaranteed.